# Webpack/Babel not detecting javascript errors before transpiling

Tags: webpack, ecmascript-6, webpack-dev-server, babeljs, babel-loader

I have configured webpack-dev-server for a new React project. I am using babel-loader to transpile ES6 code. In previous projects we were able to detect obvious errors in our javascript code prior to transpilation, eg missing import statements or undefined variables.

Why is webpack / babel-loader not detecting obvious errors? And how can I configure babel-loader to not transpile these errors and instead log to the command prompt?

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "advent-calendar",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "src/entry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --config config/webpack.config.dev.js",
    "build:webpack": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production && webpack --config config/webpack.config.prod.js",
    "build": "npm run build:webpack --verbose --color",
    "test": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development ./node_modules/.bin/mocha --opts mocha.opts",
    "test:watch": "npm run test -- --watch",
    "lint": "npm run -s lint:css:raw ; npm run -s lint:js:raw",
    "lint:css": "npm run -s lint:css:raw",
    "lint:css:raw": "stylelint \"src/**/*.{css,less,scss}\"",
    "lint:js": "npm run -s lint:js:raw",
    "lint:js:raw": "eslint  \"src/**/*.js\"",
    "lint:js:raw:fix": "./node_modules/.bin/eslint --fix \"src/**/*.js\"",
    "lint:js:watch": "esw \"src/**/*.js\" --watchyar",
    "lint:watch": "npm run lint:js:watch"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.0.2",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-es2017": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.24.1",
    "chai": "^4.1.2",
    "chai-enzyme": "^0.8.0",
    "cross-env": "^5.1.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
    "enzyme": "^3.1.1",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.0.4",
    "eslint": "^4.10.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-chai-friendly": "^0.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-eslint-comments": "^2.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.4.0",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "jsdom": "^9.9.1",
    "less": "^2.7.3",
    "less-loader": "^4.0.5",
    "mocha": "^4.0.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.6.0",
    "nyc": "~9.0.1",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "simple-jsdom": "^3.0.0",
    "sinon": "^4.1.2",
    "sinon-chai": "^2.14.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.19.0",
    "stylelint": "^8.2.0",
    "webpack": "^3.8.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "classnames": "^2.2.5",
    "crypto-js": "^3.1.9-1",
    "css-reset": "^0.0.1",
    "react": "^16.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.0.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "react-transition-group": "^2.2.1",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.2",
    "redux-saga": "^0.16.0"
  }
}
```

This is my .babelrc

```
{
   "presets": [
      "es2015", 
      "react", 
      "stage-1"
   ]
}
```

My loader for javascript files is

```
{
   test: /\.$|\.js$|\.jsx$/,
   exclude: /node_modules\/[^@]/,
   use: [{
     loader: 'babel-loader',
   }],
}
```

Comment: What types of errors do you mean? You haven't given much to go on. What specifically did you see before that you don't see now? It would also help to know what version of Webpack you are using and have your whole config.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  

Typos for example in variables aren't being picked up and imports aren't being checked if they exist. I have also edited my answer and added the entire package.json

Comment: For imports, maybe you're using `["es2015", {modules: false}],` in your other config, so that Webpack itself handles the modules? It could also be that the errors you're talking about usually seeing are from ESLint, which would be a whole separate config. Webpack/Babel don't check for general typos, though if Webpack is handling modules, it _might_ tell you if they exist?

Answer (score 1):

> And how can I configure babel-loader to not transpile these errors and instead log to the command prompt?

`Webpack-dev-server` has enough configuration for error logging, which can be provided in declarative mode.

Just use following script (name it `run-dev.js` and patch `package.json` respectively) for launching client part:

```
import webpack from 'webpack';
import WebpackDevServer from 'webpack-dev-server';

import config from './webpack.dev.config';

const outputConfig = {
    colors: true,
    hash: false,
    version: false,
    timings: false,
    assets: false,
    chunks: false,
    modules: false,
    reasons: false,
    children: false,
    source: false,
    errors: true,
    errorDetails: true,
    warnings: true,
    publicPath: false
};

const clientCompiler = webpack(config);

const clientDevServer = new WebpackDevServer(clientCompiler, {
    stats: outputConfig
});

clientDevServer.listen(3000, '127.0.0.1');
```

Then you can customize `outputConfig` object depend on requirements and verbose degree of output. Don't forget to turn on `errors` and `errorDetails` options, which will indicate chunks and source code lines with compile errors.

Read mode here https://webpack.js.org/configuration/stats/ about `outputConfig` configuration, including filter patter for error output, which can be used for excluding redundant logging in console.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have created the file but I haven't been able to execute the script. How do I execute it via package.json?

Comment: @trevorgk Replace in your package.json line `"dev": "webpack-dev-server --config config/webpack.config.dev.js"` to `"dev": "babel-node run-dev.js"`, and don't forget to `npm install --save-dev babel-cli`